# If $500! = 2^m\cdot$N, where N is an odd positive integer, then find $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Problem :

If $500! = 2^m\cdot$N, where N is an odd positive integer, then find $m$

My approach :

Shall we need to expand $500!$ and then find prime factors and see what is the power of 2 in that , please suggest some other alternative will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Do you know how many numbers below 500 are divisible by $2^n$ but not by $2^{n+1}$?

Comment: numbers like 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256

Comment: I changed my suggested method in the answer I gave, but the idea is kind of similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor$ integers less than or equal to $k$ are even. Of those, half are divisible by $4$. Of those, half are divisible by $8$. Et c.

So, sum the values $\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac{k}4\right\rfloor+\cdots$ to find the total. For $500$, this means we go to $2^8$, since it is the highest power of $2$ not greater than $500$. This is $$250+125+62+31+15+7+3+1=494$$

This is your exponent for the $2$ in the end result.